# xdvi and XQuartz hung

Tags: xdvi

I tried xdvi my file, and I got an segmentation fault. I deleted my old XQuartz, reinstalled, and now I xdvi and nothing happens. It shows it is running in the background, but nothing it showing up.

When I try to open XQuartz by itself through the OS Finder, it just bounces on the dock for some glorious moments and do nothing.

Thank you for any help!!!!

Comment: No issue here. What versions of macOS and XQuartz? Any particular reason for using `xdvi`?

Comment: Mojave and XQuartz 2.7.11. I just want to see my document change each time I compile, versus having to close and reopen a pdf if I pdflatex the document. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I use Skim that allows reloading a PDF file each time it changes. Xdvi has many shortcomings with respect to current workflows: it doesn't display rotated graphics, nor TikZ pictures.